why does jupyter notebook print such an output?
enter image description here
I used a set to assign values to names.
jupyter notebook gave this output. Can anyone explain this?
I expected {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"} as the output.
is *names a tuple?

names is a tuple, but it's holding the single set that you passed in. Get rid of the * to treat the set itself as the iterable.

Yes *x is tuple, aka *args, and **x is dictionary, aka **kwargs.

copy-n-paste code is better than linking to an image.  This isn't specialy a jupyter issue; it's a question of what *names as an argument does.  Edit your function to include print(type(names),len(names)) to get a clearer idea.  Also play with tup(*names) instead of tup(names).

maybe first use print( names ) inside function to see what you get in variable.

When you run this instruction Python creates a set object. Set doesn't guarantee that order of the elements are preserved
names = {'aaa','bbb','ccc', 'aaa'}
print (type(names)) # <class 'set'>
print(names) # {'ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa'}

Thus when you convert set to tuple the order is changed
tuple(names)   # {'ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa'}

Solution would be to convert set to list and sort the list:
f = list(names)
f.sort()  # {'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}

